# Explicit Specialization of Class Templates

Tags: linux, visual-c++

It's my code:

```
template <int T>
class Converter
{
public:
    static const int bin;
};

template<int T>
const int Converter<T>::bin = (T % 2 == 1) ? (10 * Converter<T / 2>::bin + 1) : (10 * Converter<T / 2>::bin);

template<>
const int Converter<1>::bin = 1;
```

I have in main:

```
std::cout << "dec: 1" << "\tbin: " << Converter<1>::bin << "\n";
```

For Linux and CodeBlocks on Windows this line works properly. For VS I have error:

> explicit specialization of member "Converter::bin [with T=1]" must precede its first use ()

I have no idea, how rewrite last template for int T = 1 for VS. Any ideas?

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/SLWMK86160). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie somewhere in the code you haven't shown.